# Pyspark: join some the type of date data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Forexample:
I have two dataframes in Pyspark.

A_dataframe【table name: link_data_test】,The size is so big about 1 billion rows:

```
-----+--------------------+---------------+
| id|          link_date|   tuch_url|
+-----+--------------------+-------------+
|day_1|2020-01-01 06:00:...|www.google.com|
|day_2|2020-01-01 11:00:...|www.33e.......|
|day_3|2020-01-03 22:21:...|www.3tg.......|
|day_4|2019-01-04 20:00:...|www.96g.......|
.........
+-----+--------------------+
```

B_dataframe【table name: url_data_test】:

```
-----+--------------------+
| url|          extra_date|
+-----+--------------------+
|www.google.com|2019-02-01 |
|www.23........|2020-01-02 |
|www.hsi.......|2020-01-03 |
|www.cc........|2020-01-05 |
.......
+-----+--------------------+
```

I can use the spark.sql() to create a query:

```
sql_str="""
    select
        t1.*,t2.*
    from
        link_data_test  as t1
    inner join
        url_data_test   as t2
    on
        t1.link_date> t2.extra_date and t1.link_date< date_add(t2.extra_date,8)
    where
        t1.tuch_url like "%t2.url%"
"""
test1=spark.sql(sql_str).saveAsTable("xxxx",mode="overwrite")
```

I tried this to use the following writing replace the sql wording above for some other tests,but I don't know how writing this.

```
A_dataframe.join(B_dataframe, ......,'inner').select(....).saveAsTable("xxxx",mode="overwrite")
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way.

```
df1 = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").csv("test1.csv")
df1.show(10, False)
df2 = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").csv("test2.csv")
df2.show(10, False)

+-----+-------------------+--------------+
|id   |link_date          |tuch_url      |
+-----+-------------------+--------------+
|day_1|2020-01-08 23:59:59|www.google.com|
+-----+-------------------+--------------+

+--------------+----------+
|url           |extra_date|
+--------------+----------+
|www.google.com|2020-01-01|
+--------------+----------+

df1.join(broadcast(df2), 
    col('link_date').between(col('extra_date'), date_add('extra_date', 7))
         & col('url').contains(col('tuch_url')), 'inner') \
  .show(10, False)

+-----+-------------------+--------------+--------------+----------+
|id   |link_date          |tuch_url      |url           |extra_date|
+-----+-------------------+--------------+--------------+----------+
|day_1|2020-01-08 23:59:59|www.google.com|www.google.com|2020-01-01|
+-----+-------------------+--------------+--------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!It does work. And I have a another question.Can I use '<' and '>='  in .join()？

Comment: Sure, you can use `col('link_date') > col('extra_date')` and so on, but need one more line so I didn't use.

Comment: Thanks a lot !And I tried to write following sources,but it doesn't work.
df1.join(broadcast(df2),col('link_date')>=col('extra_date')&col('link_date')<=date_add('extra_date', 7)& col('url').contains(col('tuch_url')), 'inner')

Comment: You should give the conditions with parenthesis in this way, `(col('link_date')>=col('extra_date')) & (col('link_date')<=date_add('extra_date', 7) & (...)`